# React - Objects are not valid as a React child?

Tags: reactjs

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ocjq5p)

It's just a simple style with a background image but I'm getting the error

`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {backgroundImage}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Whats does this error mean, is it not possible to do this with style. Is it possible to fix this

Comment: Off-site demos are fine, but please include the relevant code in the question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `style` attribute needs to be inside of the closing bracket:

```
<div
  style={{
    backgroundImage: ...
  }}>
</div>
```

Additional info:

- https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_attributes.asp
- https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html

Answer (score 2):

you have `style` living as descendant of `div`

```
        <div>
          style={{
              backgroundImage: 'url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff)'
          }}
        </div>
```

you need to do this:

```
        <div
          style={{
              backgroundImage: 'url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff)'
          }}>
        </div>
```

you had `style` living OUTSIDE `<div>` not inside